# How to create Case() at runtime?

Tags: python, query-builder

I want to make the Case() at runtime.

```
from pypika import Query, Table
table = Table('student')
query = Query.from_(table).select(table.name,
                         table.age,
                         table.marks,
                         Case()
                             .when(table.marks >= 90, 'A+')
                             .else('B+').as_('GRADE')
                         )
print query.get_sql()
```

Even if I make

```
case = Case()
```

I am not able to insert the expression into it using Criterion.

Basically, I want to know how to create when() statements dynamically with operators and operands being decided at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
table = Table('student')
query = Query.from_(table)
case = Case()
case = case.when(table.marks >= 90,'A+')
case = case.else_('B+').as_('Grade')
query = query.select(table.name,
                     table.age,
                     table.marks,case)
print(query.get_sql(quote_char=None))
```

The output should be something like this:

```
SELECT name,age,marks,CASE WHEN marks>=90 THEN 'A+' ELSE 'B+' END Grade FROM student
```